# ArcGIS Pro Network Analyst Routes appear to be incorrect?

Tags: network-analyst, arcgis-pro

[image]Using Network Analyst on ArcGIS Pro and a preconfigured streets network, I am trying to use the "Route" tool to solve the fastest way to service 20 different routes with 7-20 locations per route. However, each route I have solved goes completely against intuition. The stops are sequenced in ways that backtrack and cost more time than they should. For Sequence in the travel settings, I am using "Find Best." For input locations, I have separate feature classes for each of the twenty layers that contain all of the points in that route. I am trying to figure out if I am missing a crucial Network Analyst setting or if the network layer I am using might have been configured incorrectly. I included a picture of the shortest route just to showcase the type of problem I'm having.

[image: Route goes far north, south, then far north again]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your settings? I've seen odd results with a time of day set or when coming back to the start point.

Comment: I added that. I also created a new network dataset and I am still having the same issue. Routes are all over the place!

Comment: I'd try to solve individual routes: from 2 to 4 and from  2 to 3 (using the numbers shown on your image). Very unlikely, but could you have oneway restrictions on most of your roads making it impossible for the solver to travel in a certain direction (forcing your best route to go crazy)? Any live/historic traffic enabled - this could make the route to change against intuition? Any hard time windows where the stops should be visited? Also, I'd start debugging solving simple routes in a smaller area to see how the solver behave before expanding the geographic area.

Comment: Wouldn't setting Not Using Time under Arrive/Depart prevent from incorporating the traffic data? Also, in the new network dataset I created I did not set any one way restrictions (We really don't have many one way streets here anyways) and I am still getting the same results. I'll try starting a bit smaller, but it seems like at that point I am pretty much designing the routes myself.

Comment: Are you ever actually calculating a route (using a tool like find routes/generate routes/etc) or just adding stops to the map, which is what Add Locations does?

Comment: MaryBeth, I am adding locations by selecting "Import stops" then choosing the feature class with the points for that route.

Comment: Just wanted to give an update to those who helped, for some reason loading locations does not work, but if you manually select each of the points in the route it appears to route correctly. Also choosing properties and ensuring "Reorder stops to find optimal route" is a crucial.

Comment: Jeff did you solve this? I have seen some strange things myself